# Retrieving a modules dotted path name

Tags: python

suppose I import a package

```
import foo.bar.baz
```

I can find this module's filepath at `sys.modules['foo.bar.baz'].__file__`.  From this I could try to reconstruct the 'foo.bar.baz' package name. But this seems wrong.

Given a module, in variable, `m`, how do I get the dotted pathname that would be used to import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__name__) attribute should do it. See the link for the subtle difference between it and [`__package__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__)  and choose appropriately.

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom as m
>>> m.__name__
'xml.dom.minidom'
```

See [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for further details.